# Split java list into chunks start with last item in previous list

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I have a big Java `List<Object>` want to split it to small chunks,
I used [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [Lists.partition(List, int)](http://google.github.com/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) and it does its job.

**The problem here**:

If I have 2 chunked lists I want to make the first element data in the second list be the same last element data in the first list.

Any solution, Please.

**EDIT**

I mean if I have [1,2,3,4,5] and want to split it into 2 parts must be like this: [1,2,3] [3,4,5]

Comment: If I understood you correctly isn't it simple assignment ?

Comment: This list is dynamic, not fixed. So I don't know how to do this job, If it's simple to you, You can offer a help, Thanks. :)

Comment: Okey, I am not sure if you posted a question for this

    `Object lastElementOfFirstList =  firstList.get(firstList.size()-1);
    secondList.set(0, lastElementOfFirstList)`

Comment: Aren't you able to get by this?  `List<Object> head = yourList.subList(0, n);
    List<Object> tail = yourList.subList(n, yourList.length());`

Comment: Do you want partitions to intersect? Can you show us the simple input/output example?

Comment: Please provide input and expected output example

Comment: @defaultlocale The problem was with list of LatLng from Android Google Maps Directions API, I was want to draw polyline of all LatLngs I have from backend, and directions API only accept 11 points, So I must execute the process multiple time if I have more than 11 points, I already did this, but the polylines not connected with each other, That's why I asked for this solution.
sorry if my question wasn't good enough.

Comment: @Mohamed I'm glad that you have an answer now. It's still unclear though, whether you need to connect each chunk to the next one or only the first and the second to each other. The simplistic example with the list of integers will help. For example, what is the expected result when you split the list `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` to the chunks of the size 2?

Comment: @defaultlocaleif the limit is 3 it will be [1,2,3] [3,4,5] That's what i mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you

```
Object lastElementOfFirstList =  firstList.get(firstList.size()-1);
secondList.set(0, lastElementOfFirstList)
```

The above will change the first element. If you just want to append it as the first element, use `add`.

```
secondList.set(0, lastElementOfFirstList)
```

This will add and shift everything else.

Comment: Is there a solution with Guava's Lists.partition(List, int)?

Comment: @Mohamed what do you mean? can you provide an example? Say your input is `[1,2,3,4]` and you want to partition them by two. What would the result be?

Comment: @Mohamed Notice that [`List.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) will replace the first element of the second list. It's unclear from your question whether this is acceptable or not.

Comment: @defaultlocale I used List.add() instead.